# Why are [$p] characters appearing at the beginning of every file?

Tags: echo

Every file I open in vim lately, even new empty files, as a ($p) at the beginning. This does not appear to be real - inserting text overwrites it, and once it's overwritten it does not return.

I recently reinstalled vim (through homebrew) and suspect that may have been the origin of the problem, but reinstalling again does not fix it. `vim -U NONE` still adds the characters to the beginning as well, which from what .

I have no idea what might be doing this, or how to fix it. It's easy enough to ignore, but I can't help but wonder what's causing it.

Comment: Try putting either `set t_RS=` or `set t_SH=` in your vimrc, as mentioned in the linked question